After Upgrade to Maui, Build exception "error XAGJS7001: System.NullReferenceException" at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.XAJavaTypeScanner.GetJavaTypes
Background:
An app that runs on Windows, Android, and iOS.

Separate projects. Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, WPF.
NOT Xamarin.Forms. We do our own rendering via SkiaSharp and OpenGL.
Almost all source files are shared between the platforms.
Works (and can be built) today on all platforms.

BUT starting this month, Apple rejects app upgrades unless they run on iOS 17 SDK. Which isn't supported by Xamarin. And Xamarin has reached end of life.

Decided it was time to upgrade to .Net 8.
Decided to upgrade the Android version first.

Migrating to Maui:
Ran .Net Upgrade Assistant to migrate a Xamarin.Android app (no Xamarin.Forms) on .Net Framework 4.7 to .Net 8 and Maui.
Xamarin.Essentials handled most of what we needed for platform-specifics. Replaced with appropriate Maui packages.
Possible complications in our app:

two Xamarin.Android dlls. A main project and a class library.
ancient project layout. First version was years ago.
a C++ dll.
third party libraries.
many, many lines of C# code, in hundreds of classes.

Current Status:

Compilation of dlls succeeds.
Debug Build: Linking SdkOnly.
PublishTrimmed false (get back to errors in that in a separate question later)

System.NullReferenceException at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.XAJavaTypeScanner.GetJavaTypes.

I have not found anywhere on internet with this problem at this step in build process.

Complete list of errors in VS output:
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error XAGJS7001: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error XAGJS7001:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.XAJavaTypeScanner.GetJavaTypes(ICollection`1 inputAssemblies, XAAssemblyResolver resolver)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error XAGJS7001:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(XAAssemblyResolver res, Boolean useMarshalMethods)
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error XAGJS7001:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.RunTask()
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error XAGJS7001:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 25

Questions:
How find the cause of the internal build errors above?
What about our app might lead to this?


ancient project layout. First version was years ago.

This was the cause of the symptom. Creating a new .Net 8 Maui project, and adding our sources (modified for Maui by .Net Upgrade Assistant), fixed it.
Did not bother to determine which of the old settings caused the failure.
